# Get color codes in string

Tags: php

I have a string like

```
<font color="#ffffff">Heippa </font><b><i><u><font face="Calibri" color="#e71818">rallaa</font></u></i></b>
```

And I need to get all color codes seperated in a array

```
['#ffffff','#e71818']
```

Is there a easy way to do this. I know you can use **strrchr** to find all # marks and **substr($color, 0, 7)**, but that will print out only the last found mark.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: have a look at using regex to match them all: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: You can use `preg_match_all` to search for strings that start with # and follow with 6 characters, letters a-f and numbers 0-9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for matching CSS hex colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837942/regex-for-matching-css-hex-colors)

Comment: Did anyone of you think about `<font color="blue">` or `color="#123"` ? Use `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML`....

Answer (score 1):

```
 $input='<font color="#ffffff">Heippa </font><b><i><u><font face="Calibri" color="#e71818">rallaa</font></u></i></b>';   
 preg_match_all("/#[0-9a-f]{6}/i", $input, $output);
 print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example works for your HTML:

```
<?php

$html = '<font color="#ffffffa">Heippa </font><b><i><u><font face="Calibri" color="#e71818">rallaa</font></u></i></b>';

$matches = array();

$found = preg_match_all('/#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}/i', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

if ($found) {

    $result = array();

    foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
        // Key $m for unique result:
        $result[$m] = $m;
    }

    print_r($result);

}
```

But not for this HTML:

```
color="#0123456789abcdef"  // will match #012345
color="red"
```